# if in category but only with post meta

Tags: posts, customization, categories, custom-field, post-meta

Working on an if statement to display text only if it's in a specific category WITH specific post meta. If the post meta doesn't match but it's in this category, the text should not display. This is showing the text even if it's not the the "**secret category**" category. I don't know what to do beyond this.

```
if( in_category('secret-category') &&  $stat == 'NFS Stat' || $stat == 'Sold Stat' ) 
{ 
    echo 'Do something here.'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just have an [operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) issue.

Your logic here will always return true if $stat == 'Sold Stat' regardless of the result of in_category('secret-category').

Try this, the extra parenthesis will force the || statement to be evaluated separately:

```
    if (in_category('secret-category') && ($stat == 'NFS Stat' || $stat == 'Sold Stat')) {
        echo 'Do something here.';
    }
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! That worked!